# How do I insert a loop within a command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, centos7

For instance : command (--option * 4 times)

Can I use for loop here. Kindly suggest!

In other words

```
command --option1 --option2 --option3 --option3 --option3
```

So I want option3 in a loop.

Comment: Shall that expand to  `command --option --option --option --option` or to `command --option command --option command --option command --option` or to what?

Comment: [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050#I.27m_constructing_a_command_based_on_information_that_is_only_known_at_run_time) is pertinent.

Comment: The first one you thought is what I am struggling with.

Comment: I don't see something 4 times now. I see 1,2,3 or 3,3,3. What is your real problem, you want to solve?

Comment: Why is this tagged kvm or centos7?

Comment: @Robert The kvm tag looks totally irrelevant, so I removed it. The centos7 tag is relevant, because it allows determining the bash version.

Answer (score 1):

See [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) for a discussion of why naive attempts at solving this problem often fail (or initially appear to work, but then fail when leveraged with more interesting data or more problematic scenarios).

An approach that's cautious to follow best practices may look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

number_of_option3s=4
args=( )
for ((i=0; i<number_of_option3s; i++)); do
  args+=( --option3 )
done

your_command --option1 --option2 "${args[@]}"
```

Presumably in a real-world use case, you'd be amending `args+=( --option="$i" )` or iterating over filenames and doing something like `for file in *.txt; do args+=( --input "$file" ); done`; all these will work.

---

If you aren't running with bash and instead need to use `/bin/sh`, this gets uglier:

```
#!/bin/sh

# need to use a function since there's only one array, "$@", but it has a separate
# instance per stack depth.
call_with_repeated_option() {
  number_of_options=$1; shift
  option_to_append=$1; shift
  i=0
  while [ "$i" -lt "$number_of_options" ]; do
    set -- "$@" "$option_to_append"
    i=$((i + 1))
  done
  "$@"
}

# call your_command with 4 "--option3" arguments after --option1 and --option2
call_with_repeated_option 4 --option3 your_command --option1 --option2
```

Comment: @scorp, that means your shell isn't bash. Be sure you're running it with `bash scriptname`, not `sh scriptname`, and that you keep the shebang as `#!/bin/bash`, `#!/usr/bin/env bash` or similar, **not** `#!/bin/sh`.

Answer (score -2):

With:

```
echo "--option"{0..3}
--option0 --option1 --option2 --option3

 echo "--option"{1,2,3,3,3}
--option1 --option2 --option3 --option3 --option3
```

Here, the command echo is invoked with "--option", glued to the result of the expansion of (0 to 3) or, in the second case, with the list of elements, separated by comma.

```
echo "--option"{1..13..4}
--option1 --option5 --option9 --option13
```

This related construct is to read 1 to 13 by 4.

What Sir Duffy requests in the command is a different question, but easy to solve in a similar manner:

```
echo command $(echo "--option=\""{a.file,b.file,d.file,e.file}"\"" )
command --option="a.file" --option="b.file" --option="d.file" --option="e.file"
```

Comment: This pattern has a significant performance penalty (the subshell and pipeline incur `fork()` costs), and doesn't hold up to real-world use cases, which typically involve something like `--option="filename here"` (where the argument being added varies with uncontrolled data and thus needs to be able to survive string-splitting).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Performance penalty, for an interactive command? Really? Your real world use-case wasn't asked for. Maybe your mind reading capabilities exceed mine.

Comment: You could get the same without `sed` with `command {,,,}--option` or perhaps `command $(printf -- '--option %0.s' {1..4})` would do.

Comment: @Pesa, yes, the possibilities to solve it are endless. However, 4 sed invocations aren't a deal on.

Comment: @userunknown yep, but it looks cleaner :)

Comment: @userunknown, we're here to be a teaching resource. Teaching a practice that's prone to misbehavior is hardly defensible. And *if* the OP were asking how to write something that was only useful as an interactive command and not in a scripted context, then it would be off-topic here (and we'd be wanting to send them over to [unix.se]).

Comment: @PesaThe, ...one issue with `{,,,}` (while generally a decent answer, if the OP really did want a constant number of repetitions) is that the OP appears to be using `/bin/sh` (despite mistagging the question as bash). Brace expansion isn't available in baseline POSIX shells.

Comment: @userunknown, your `echo` command *echos* a string with a correctly quoted command, but it won't *execute* as that string if you take the `echo` out. See [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) for a full discussion of why that's the case.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy True, should've occurred to me when I saw the `line 3 syntax error` ;)

Comment: @userunknown I also don't really understand the updated answer now. It calls `x` with 4 *different* options and not one of them is repeated as required.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: You can always imagine a generalization, for which a specific solution is too specific. in --option or --option1 for the now updated question, there is no splitting to prevent. Nor do we have to fear the forking costs for 4 options.  ls -l {'bb bb','dd dd','ff ff'} works on my machine and I use it, if necessary, but not when not. Cases with filenames might be better suited for find. Hard to tell, without context. I can call `touch {1..5}" "file.tar.gz` and then `ls {1..5}" "file.tar.gz` or `ls [1-5]" "file.tar.gz` but would prefer `ls [1-5]*`, depending on the context.

Comment: @PesaThe: Nothing calls x. Echo is called. X is just a dummy. The question was updated and now talks about --option1 --option2 ... but still about 4 times. So i took --option0 ... --option3, not realizing, that the --option3 is repeated, but only 3 times, --option1 and 2 only to disturb us. I guess we wait a few weeks, until scorp knows, what he is after.

Comment: @userunknown Yup, I know `x` is just a dummy :) I was confused by the options. I think OP just simply wants to use a command with a couple of different options and use one of them repeatedly in a more "efficient" way than writing them down `n` times, that's all there is to it, I think. Probably something like `--verbose`.

Comment: @PesaThe: Well, except from the verbose option, I never saw an option, which was useful to call multiple times in a row. I guess it meanwhile was condensed to -vv and used more than two times, but I'm not sure. `lsusb` once had such a thing, if I remember correctly.

Comment: @userunknown, to explain briefly: The OP is asking a simplified version of a question *that is a FAQ*. This FAQ has accepted best-practice answers that work in general, non-simplified cases, and those best-practice answers work here as well. This is thus an excellent chance to teach the general-purpose approach (which works for their trivial case but also nontrivial ones as well); teaching an approach tailored to the special case means that one *also* needs to teach the boundaries of that special case, and the details of when the specific approach does or doesn't apply.

Comment: I spent half a decade or so as a channel regular in freenode's #bash, and one of the things that was a plague on us was people trying to apply practices they saw in examples given in TLDP's ABS. Those practices often were safe in the specific context of the example, but when someone learns something, they generally do that with the intent to be able to apply it more widely; and people *did*, in practice, try to apply things they saw in ABS examples outside their intended, safe scope all the damned time.

Comment: So, to explain why I'm militant here: I've been down this road, and I know where it ends: It ends with people trying to blindly apply practices which are safe only in narrow circumstances *outside of those circumstances*, and then asking new questions on account of same (or, worse, releasing buggy scripts into the wild -- some of which, like Apache Tomcat's startup scripts, can't be fixed without breaking backwards compatibility, and thus *stay* broken forever).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Your high standards and general approach in all honour. My  perspective to this is, that we don't know scorp, we know close to nothing about him, he has 1 rep. point and wrote a question which was changed multiple times and is still unclear. I can speculate, what he might be after and I encourage speculating on facts and reasonable assumptions. However, an answer, which answers the specific question in a simple way is sometimes better than a general, but complex answer. If you feel overqualified for simple tasks, that's a pity.

Comment: … As long as you can't show, why my solution doesn't work or is not acceptable in terms of performance (cost of 4 forks), it's just a matter of taste, how to teach and how to learn things. As a programmer, I know of possible pitfalls with problematic filenames and calling sed 1000 times in a row. It's not in the scope of the question, but premature optimization. I can't see how apache Tomcat startup scripts are related to 3 or 4 times --option. Maybe you should write a blogpost about it. If it is well written and insightful, I'll appreciate it.

Comment: … As long as I haven't read it, I treat it as anecdotical evidence. Yes, people learn incrementally and ask new questions, after learning one thing. Violating the borders of an working example is a learning experience and for most people a way to learn. Just studying references often fails to teach the people anything. You're still lacking an example, where my approach will fail.